# Codebuild project, access secret as env vars from another account

Tags: aws-codebuild

How can I access secrets that are on account B. My buildspec on account A looks this way? When running codebuild project I have an error - Secrets Manager can't find the specified secret.

Plese see a picture attached.

[image: 1]

buildspec.yaml

Comment: Please post the error as text , not an image.

Comment: Issue is solved, you should use arn if this is another account and not a name of a secret.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue is solved, you should use arn if this is another account and not a name of a secret.